# YA Novel published before 1994 where characters are all cockroaches living in suburbia

Tags: story-identification, novel, animals, urban-fantasy

I remember reading this novel way back in high school in the early 1990s.  All the characters are cockroaches and are living in a backyard in the suburbs.  I don't know any of the names of the characters.  The main character wants to fly but is discouraged by the colony elders.  The novel explores the cockroach society and the main character's relationship with his fellow cockroaches. There is romance, drama and an execution.  They get drunk off soapy water from the drains. At the end, the colony does end up flying due to the updraft from the fire in the garden shed.

Answer (score 5):

It’s called *The Collectors* (1994) by Robert Carter.

From [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0688137636):

> A renegade band of "collectors," cockroach-like insects, have organized themselves into territorial "circles" and raid their human cohabitants for food scraps (described in fantasy vernacular as "chumps" and "spills"). Edwud K, on a mission from the Director, strikes out with a small cadre of followers to search for the crucial "Monoocal," which reflects the image of "our otherselves." The group's adventures include recovering from a near-fatal dose of insecticide while finding asylum in a greenhouse; a mystical encounter with a camera lens in a movie theater; and a visit to a church.